# Energy-Momentum Tensor not traceless?

Tags: electromagnetism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, covariance, trace

In my university, we have a different approach for deriving the energy-momentum tensor for electromagnetic field in vacuum. The result is:

$T_i {_j} = \epsilon_0 \ (\frac{1}{2}E^2 \delta_i {_j}\  - E_iE_j) + \frac{1}{\mu_0} \ (\frac{1}{2}B^2\delta_i {_j}-B_iB_j) $

$ T_4 {_j} = \frac{i}{c} S_j$

$ T_j {_4} = icg_j $

$ T_4 {_4} = -w_e {_m} $

With

$ $$\vec{S} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} ($$\vec{E} \ \times \ $$\vec{B}) $

$ $$\vec{g} = \epsilon_0\  (E \ \times \ B) $

$ w_e {_m} = \frac{1}{2}\ (\epsilon_0E^2 \ + \ \frac{1}{\mu_0}B^2) $

With this tensor I can derive the conservation laws of energy and momentum, but it is not traceless. In other books, I haven't seen this tensor with complex elements.

Is this a valid tensor? Is it not traceless due to the derivation with complex 4-vectors?

Comment: It is traceless.

Comment: @my2cts in my case?

Comment: Yes, your expressions describe a traceless tensor. $T_{44}- T_{11}-T_{22}-T_{33}=0$

Comment: @my2cts Sorry, but I thought that I must sum all the terms. Can you explain me why it is minus for the first three terms?

Comment: Your prof is using the deprecated $ict$ metric. The minus signs come from $i^2=-1$.

Comment: It is because of the indefinite metric of Minkowski space.